# attach a JS function to pug to create a dynamic url

Tags: javascript, pug

Is there anyway I can attach a JS function to pug. I have variable name which gets the value from e.target.value and attaches it to the url for the form sub

```
 -const name ="";
    -function enteringName() {
            -console.log("sdf");
            -name  = e.target.value;

    -};

<h1>Log in</h1>
<form action="/users/:"+name  method="POST" id="loginForm" >
  <label for="username">username:</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" onchange={enteringName())}/><br />
  <label for="password">password:</label><br />
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
  <br />
</form>
```